# Java sockets - Why do I need a PrintWriter to make this work?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to learn socket programming in Java but unfortunately I'm running into some behaviour that I don't understand. I have a very simple client program that connect to a server socket and sends some text that gets echoed back. Said client program looks like this:

```
try(
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5001);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
){
    String userInput = "";
    while (!userInput.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
        userInput = stdIn.readLine();
        writer.write(userInput);
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println("Server response: " + reader.readLine());    
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

When I run this program the first line that I enter gets sent to the server but after that I can enter as many lines as I want and nothing gets sent. I also never see anything printed out by the `System.out.println()` line.

But if I switch out the `OutputStreamWriter` for a `PrintWriter` everything works as it should! Here's the code with `PrintWriter`:

```
try(
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5001);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
){
    String userInput = "";
    while (!userInput.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
        userInput = stdIn.readLine();
        writer.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("Server response: " + reader.readLine());    
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Anyone have any idea why the first of the above two programs acts weird while the second one works? If anyone can tell me what the difference between writing with an `OutputStreamWriter` vs a `PrintWriter` is then that might tell me what's going on.

Comment: Maybe your server-program is reading from the socket using `readLine()`? Note that `println()` adds a linebreak after the data and `write()` doesn't, so in the first case the server will wait forever for the end of the line to read.

Comment: That's it, the problem got solved when I manually added a line break when writing with the OutputStreamWriter, thanks.

Comment: @piet.t I think for the purpose of closing the question, you should add this as an answer

Comment: @Dmitry Ginzburg: done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the difference between `write()` and `println()` is that `println()` adds a linebreak after the data while `write()` does not.

So if your server uses `readLine()` to receive the data with a client using `write()` it might wait forever for the end of the line to read without receiving it.

So `writer.write(userInput + "\n")` might do the trick.